# How is memory handled in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how memory is held in a React component's lifecycle. Is memory blocked out for each component and is it wiped every time a component is unmounted?

Any degree of explanation both short and long are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses garbage collection. Roughly speaking, once there are no more references to an object, the memory it consumes can be released. The actual algorithm for what can be garbage collected is a bit more complicated than that (it's called "mark and sweep"), but you can read some about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm

An unmounted component will have no more references, at least none on react's side. So as long as you're not keeping references around, it can be garbage collected.